# how can I get the POST body when using apache mod_auth_form

Tags: apache

I'm trying to use mod_auth_form using the mode described in the documentation as "Inline Login with Body Preservation".  In the documentation they mention using mod_include or a CGI as the ErrorDocument in order to generate the login form, e.g.:

ErrorDocument 401 /cgi-bin/login.cgi

The scenario is if a user wants to POST from either a non-authenticated page, or from an authenticated page with a timed-out session.

The POST hits the target url, is intercepted by mod_auth_form, which invokes the ErrorDocument 401, the user enters credentials. On the login form page, a "special" hidden form variable httpd_body can be added (and httpd_method) which will be processed by the authentication handler to create a POST body to the original target.

The problem is the the login.cgi doesn't get the POST data since (apparently) apache doesn't pass the POST data to an ErrorDocument. The alternative to ErrorDocument is to use the directive AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation however this does a plain 302 redirect and of course the POST data is lost.

It seems the feature for httpd_body is impossible to use, as it is impossible to capture the original POST data.  Even in the case of a GET, one would have to parse the referrer to get the GET variables.

Is there a way in Apache to read the POST data and store it somewhere before the authentication hook is run?  Or some other solution I've missed?

Comment: Ok. This may be an apache http bug, see https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53692